# Function calls are not supported in decorators in animation

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-aot

> ERROR in
>   src/app/components/register/registration-form/registration-form.component.ts(27,18):
>   Error during template compile of 'RegistrationFormComponent'
>   Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'getanimationRule'
>   was called.

RegistrationFormComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration-form',
  templateUrl: './registration-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration-form.component.scss'],
  animations:[getanimationRule(registerChildrens)]
})
```

getanimationRule

```
export function  getanimationRule(routeCollection: Routes)  {
    const routeArray = routeCollection.map(o => o.data && o.data.animation ? o.data.animation : null)
    .filter((el) => el != null);
    const animationRules = [];
    routeArray.forEach((element, value) => {
        if (element != null) {
            if (value === 0) {
                animationRules.push(transition(element + ' => *', animationDOWN));
            } else if (value === routeArray.length - 1) {
                animationRules.push(transition(element + '=> *', animationUP));
            } else {
                routeArray.forEach((subelement, subvalue) => {
                    if (subelement != null) {
                        if (subvalue < value) {
                            animationRules.push(transition(element + ' => ' + subelement, animationUP));
                        } else if (subvalue > value) {
                            animationRules.push(transition(element + ' => ' + subelement, animationDOWN));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return trigger('routeAnimations',animationRules );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, You can't call a function inside component decorator, you can just pass it as a reference like

```
animations: [getanimationRule]
```

follow this link for more info -> [Medium](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/total-guide-to-dynamic-angular-animations-that-can-be-toggled-at-runtime-be5bb6778a0a)